# How can I find the exported function name from ordinal (export by ordinal)?

Tags: export, portable-executable, ordinals

I trying in export directory ,i got the exported function name(export by name) by browsing the directory with help of addressoffnnames property ....Here ,Example in comctl32.dll (api) total fn names 420 ,but no of fnnames 118(export by name) ,other 302 fns are exported by ordinal only...i also trying dumpbin it does not show anything(fn name with respect to ordinal) from ordinal...help me ,how to relate api with ordinal to retrieve exported functions name...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the "Dependency Walker" utility which is available in Visaul Studio package. It can list both the ordinal and export name and allows you to sort on each.