# "The Ordinal 112 could not be located in dynamic link library..."

Tags: windows, ssl, dll, openssl, ordinal

The Whole Error is as follows: " The ordinal 112 could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\GNU-C-compiler\GNUstep\bin\openssl.exe "

i've been searching around a lot on the web for a solution to no avail. I recently started getting into encryption using OpenSSL however during the process of installation i installed multiple different version of the software for testing but during my deletion of these other versions i just deleted the folder instead of doing the proper uninstall procedure (the openssl program saves some dll's into the windows system directory so these multiple dll's were kept). Thus i believe that these extra dll's are the source of the problem (maybe) but i cant find a way to easily uninstall them and so i am asking for a reasonable solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, that means something that there's a version mismatch with DLLs. You can probably get hold of a statically-linked version, or put the correct versions of the DLLs in the same directory as it?

Comment: hello Rup, i was able to get it to work by reinstalling the OpenSSL program, but instead saving the ddl's into a local bin folder and not in the windows system directory

Answer (score -1):

> “The Ordinal 112 could not be located in dynamic link library…”

I'm speculating its `SSLv23_server_method` or `BN_MONT_CTX_free` from OpenSSL 1.0.2; or `RSA_PSS_PARAMS_free` or `SSL_CONF_CTX_clear_flags` from OpenSSL 1.1.0. Based on some recent changes, I'm guessing its OpenSSL 1.0.2 and `SSLv23_server_method`.

```
# OpenSSL 1.1.0
$ find $PWD -type f -iname '*.num' -exec grep " 112" {} \;
RSA_PSS_PARAMS_free                     112 1_1_0   EXIST::FUNCTION:RSA
SSL_CONF_CTX_clear_flags                112 1_1_0   EXIST::FUNCTION:
...

# OpenSSL 1.0.2
$ find $PWD -type f -iname '*.num' -exec grep " 372" {} \;
BN_MONT_CTX_free                        112 EXIST::FUNCTION:
SSLv23_server_method                    112 EXIST::FUNCTION:RSA
...
```

You will need to verify it by using [`dumpbin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y05bd5.aspx) or [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Also see [How can I find the exported function name from ordinal (export by ordinal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005348/608639) on Stack Overflow.

---

The ordinals are created using `<openssl src>\util\mkdef.pl`. You can see the source code from OpenSSL's GitHub presence. [Here is 1.0.2](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/util/mkdef.pl) and [here is 1.1.0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/util/mkdef.pl).

Here are the head comments for the file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
#
# generate a .def file
#
# It does this by parsing the header files and looking for the
# prototyped functions: it then prunes the output.
#
# Intermediary files are created, call libcrypto.num and libssl.num,
# The format of these files is:
#
#   routine-name    nnnn    vers    info
#
# The "nnnn" and "vers" fields are the numeric id and version for the symbol
# respectively. The "info" part is actually a colon-separated string of fields
# with the following meaning:
#
#   existence:platform:kind:algorithms
#
# - "existence" can be "EXIST" or "NOEXIST" depending on if the symbol is
#   found somewhere in the source, 
# - "platforms" is empty if it exists on all platforms, otherwise it contains
#   comma-separated list of the platform, just as they are if the symbol exists
#   for those platforms, or prepended with a "!" if not.  This helps resolve
#   symbol name variants for platforms where the names are too long for the
#   compiler or linker, or if the systems is case insensitive and there is a
#   clash, or the symbol is implemented differently (see
#   EXPORT_VAR_AS_FUNCTION).  This script assumes renaming of symbols is found
#   in the file crypto/symhacks.h.
#   The semantics for the platforms is that every item is checked against the
#   environment.  For the negative items ("!FOO"), if any of them is false
#   (i.e. "FOO" is true) in the environment, the corresponding symbol can't be
#   used.  For the positive itms, if all of them are false in the environment,
#   the corresponding symbol can't be used.  Any combination of positive and
#   negative items are possible, and of course leave room for some redundancy.
# - "kind" is "FUNCTION" or "VARIABLE".  The meaning of that is obvious.
# - "algorithms" is a comma-separated list of algorithm names.  This helps
#   exclude symbols that are part of an algorithm that some user wants to
#   exclude.
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem using OpenSSL 1.0.2g - the missing function was "SSLv2_client_method" (113, the missing ordinal message seems to be off-by-one).

Changes between 1.0.2f and 1.0.2g [1 Mar 2016]

- Disable SSLv2 default build, default negotiation and weak ciphers. SSLv2 is by default disabled at build-time.  Builds that are not configured with "enable-ssl2" will not support SSLv2.