# The ordinal 372 could not located in the dynamic link library

Tags: php, apache, ssl, openssl, localhost

I am installing SSL on my localhost. When I try to run

```
 openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048
```

command in cmd, I got an error warning.

> The ordinal 372 could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   D:\wamp64\bin\apache2.4.23\bin\openssl.exe.

I have installed Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.0b from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.htmlhttp://)

What should I do to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Also see [Can't find ordinal 372 in WAMP/Apache's openssl.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36238887) and [“The Ordinal 112 could not be located in dynamic link library…”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36163468)

Comment: You need to use the OpenSSL built with Apache 2.4.23. You can't mix and match them, like downloading OpenSSL from another source. Sometimes you can, but if you run into this issue, then you can't :)

Answer (score -1):

first check if you have already installed some other application which is using the same. if that is so make sure that you update the links from that directory.
on the other hand it seems that your Wampserver in that install did not create the symbolic links to the OpenSSL dlls in the PHP folder as it does on some newer machine so you have to create the exact same links OpenSSL failed. delete the links, installed OpenSSL on the machine and copied the exe, dll and cnf files to the required locations in Wampserver and all will work.

Comment: you want me to uninstall the openssl and install it again.. I have tried this trick so many times and also with different versions of openssl. here is one question, I always select the option "The windows system directory" for additional tasks during installation. There was another option "The openssl libraries (/bin) directory". should I select the 2nd one?

Comment: @AkifHussainSayyed -- I experienced this problem because I was using WampServer 3 on Win10. I was able to fix this problem without re-installing using [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238887/cant-find-ordinal-372-in-wamp-apaches-openssl-exe/39895608#39895608).