# WAMPx64 / Openssl Ordinal 372 cannot be locatied

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, wamp, ordinal

I'm trying to generate an SSL cert.

But I've run into this error while doing so:

> The **ordinal 372** could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.7\bin\openssl.exe

I've been searching around for awhile but the solutions aren't detailed enough. I've also no experience in generating SSL certs.

I've also tried using dependency walker and it generated:

> Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>
> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>
> Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.

But I don't know how to continue from here.

Please provide detailed solution on how to **resolve this** and **generate an SSL cert**. Thanks.

Comment: [This post may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312) Basically the `openssl.exe` released by Apache does nto always seem to match everything else. Install a new WIN_OPENSSL and it should work

Comment: Also see [WAMP OpenSSL ordinal 372 error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36238887) on Stack Overflow; and [Changing/deleted ordinals for exported function in the Windows DLLs](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.dev/MKPriXdccZ0) on the OpenSSL dev mailing list.

Comment: @RiggsFolly up I did that and it works now. Thanks