# Ordinal 372 could not be located in the dynamic link library. Wamp openssl error

Tags: c++, ssl, https, openssl, wamp

I am stuck in the following error for a very long time.

"The ordinal 372 could not be located in the dynamic link libray C:\wamp64\bin\apache2.4.24\bin\openssl.exe.

My configurations are

1) Windows 10 (64 bit)

2) apache 2.4.24
I followed following tutorial ([Installation SSL in wamp server: Error in httpd-ssl.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312)) and ended up in following error

"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 177 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1."

For the above post I downloaded (Win64OpenSSL-1_1_0e) openssl version.

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64bit WAMPServer. Even if your OS is 64bit, if you are using WAMPServer 32bit, you must download the 32bit OpenSSL

Comment: [Wamp2 and “The ordinal 942 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY.dll”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6178815/608639), [WAMPx64 / Openssl Ordinal 372 cannot be located](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38046271/608639), [Can't find ordinal 372 in WAMP/Apache's openssl.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36238887/608639), [“The Ordinal 112 could not be located in dynamic link library…”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36163468/608639), etc.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am using 64 bit wampserver.